# Prove Wold's theorem from abstract Wold's decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, operator-theory, operator-algebras, time-series

I see that [Wold's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem) in time series analysis is proven by the abstract [Wold's decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_decomposition) in operator theory. The abstract theorem states that:

> Every isometry is a direct sum of copies of the unilateral shift and a unitary operator.

I want to understand intuitively the connection between the two theorems: so in the time series version $Y_t = \sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j \epsilon_{t-j} + \eta_t$, which are the isometry, the shift and the unitary operator?

*PS: I see in some document which states the lag operator is the isometry, then which is the shift operator in the time series version?*